# Really Confused about SharePoint Sites structure

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-project

I know I have a lot of reading to do, but right off the bat I have some questions about my new Sharepoint 2010/Project 2010 implementation.

When I finished my first `SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard` and go to my sharepoint's url, I'm greeted by the site templates screen.  I was just testing and I created a team meeting site.  After doing so I was never able to get back to the site templates screen, and my sharepoint url (sharepoint.mydomain.com) became the first site.  To me, it seems the first site you make becomes the base site (right?) and any other sites created afterwards fall Under the base site.

I guess I had this all wrong and thought you could have side-by-side sites.  If this isn't the case then the base site really needs to be designated as the 'entrance' to the sharepoint server right?

Are there any good resources for understanding this concept?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a SharePoint web application, as you discovered, you need to have a root site collection.  It is a common practice to pick either a team site template or a publishing template for the root site collection.  It doesn't really matter, as long as it meets your needs.

You can't "get back to the template selection screen" once the site collection has been created.  A way to go about doing this would be to delete the site collection in the Central Administrator and then recreate it with the template you need.

There is a ton of information available on how SharePoint site topologies work.  Amazon has a lot of books available (search for "SharePoint 2010 Administration").  A good starting point might be a few of the videos [here](http://www.sharepoint-videos.com/sharepoint-2010/).

Once you have your web application created along with the root site collection (http://sharepoint.mydomain.com), you can then create additional site collections (http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/sites/site1) and/or sub-sites (http://sharepoint.mydomain.com/subsite) which will live below that web application.

You also have the option of creating additional web applications in the same farm (http://sharepointapp2.mydomain.com) which will then have its own site collections and subsites.  This may be what you you consider "side by side sites."

Comment: Thank you!  After reading this it makes sense and I was able to make my first root site collection. Thank you!